# Reset form for new validation, rails 3.1

Tags: reset, client-side-validation, rails-3.1

in my rails 3.1 app I have one form that needs to be used several times. I have a list of project groups and form for new below. After create I render new group after all existing and do $('#new_project_group')[0].reset(). It makes the form empty, but I have problem with validations.

I use client side validations gem and on second time validation doesn't work. I think that this is because one time field was filled and the second time is not validating anymore.

Does anybody know how to reset form with validations?

UPD
Here is code for another model, but with the same problem. Here I render dialog with form and after adding dialog is hiding. Next time I just open the same dialog with reseted form.

Controller:

```
class Accounts::FeedbackMessagesController < Accounts::ApplicationController
defaults :resource_class => FeedbackMessage
load_resource :feedback_message
respond_to :js

def create 
    @feedback_message.user_id = current_user.id
    @feedback_message.user_email = current_user.email
    @feedback_message.user_name = current_user.full_name
    create!
end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for resource, :remote => true, :validate => true do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs do %>  
    <%= f.input :description, :input_html => {:id => 'test'} %>

        <br/>
  <div class="links">
      <%=link_to_add_association t('asset.add'), f, :assets %>  
    </div>

<%end%>
<%= f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button :button_html => { :disable_with => "#{t('share.wait')}" } %>
<% end %>
 <% end %>
```

new.js.coffee:

```
if $('#feedback_dialog').html() == ""
$('#feedback_dialog').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'form') %>').dialog(
  open: ->
    $('form[data-validate]').validate()
  close: ->
    $("#feeadback_dialog_link").click -> 
      $('#feedback_dialog').dialog "open"
      return false
)
 else
$('#feedback_dialog').dialog "open"
```

create.js.coffee:

```
  $('#feedback_dialog').dialog "close"
  $('#new_feedback_message')[0].reset()
```

Comment: It would help if you gave the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue:

User clicks link and popups up modal with a form 
User fills in invalid data and then closes modal 
--At this point I want to clear all of the errors of the form-- 
User opens form to a fresh form

I did it at the FIELD level as I only have 2 fields out of 5 that I want to clear the errors from. It probably can be done at the form level, however I've never tried.

How clientside validations work is that it stores data on the actual element (this is a text input), like so:
$('#edit_event_title').data();

When the page loads it looks like this:
$('#edit_event_title').data()
Object
validate: true
**proto**: Object

Now, if you punch in some invalid data and leave the field using [the default error rendering](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Error-Rendering) it will display some error fields. It also updates your element to this:
$('#edit_event_title').data()
Object
**changed: false

valid: false**
validate: true
proto: Object

Now what we need to do remove the field marked as having an error (and remove the error text) is to remove the 2 fields added in the data, and run a function that's built into the client_side_validations gem:

```
$('#edit_event_title').removeData("changed");
$('#edit_event_title').removeData("valid");
$('#edit_event_title').trigger('element:validate:pass')
```

From what I can tell the actual library "rails.validations.js"/client_side_validation gem doesn't have any specific functions for removing an error on demand (everything looks to be in callbacks).

If anyone has a better solution please let me know. Otherwise, the above will let you remove client_side_validations on demand.

Comment: I found solution that is similar to yours - I call .change() to every input on validated form and value is reseted, so validation began to work again

Comment: FWIW I found that Ryanon's solution above with the removeData and trigger worked, Link_er's solution did not work for my particular situation. YMMV.